# MySQL Error Number 1064

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `etl_users_banned` (
>    `id` mediumint(5) NOT NULL AUT' at line 14

How to fix this?

here's my code

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `etl_users_banned` (
  `id` mediumint(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `protection` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=58 ;
```

Comment: It works [**see fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a65e) show us the whole code

Comment: cant send it its too long

Comment: can i post external links?

Comment: just download it plz its still like that

Comment: Sir i am really sorry fixed it using sql fiddle thanks thanks :D